# How to fix an oscillating fan that runs slow?

Tags: fans, electric-motor

I have an oscillating fan that does turn on and does oscillate, but which does not run at the correct speed.

Normally, when I turn it on it starts at the highest speed and I can change speeds if I want. Now, however, when I turn it on it starts at a relatively low speed and I hear a steady hum. I am unable to change speeds.

How do I identify what might be the issue?

Comment: Disconnect from the wall and have a look.  Its possible it just gummed by household dust and fluff.  Remove carefully and try again.

Comment: Anything of remotely current production (last 20-30 years) - junk, recycle or trash, buy new fan. Serviceability is not typical.